# How to SELECT multiple values in MYSQL trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

how can I SELECT multiple values INTO variables in MYSQL trigger?
I have tried SELECT values into variables in this way but it didn't work. I was inspired by this thread [how to use trigger to set value based on query result](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103080/how-to-use-trigger-to-set-value-based-on-query-result).
When I examined value in variables, it is NULL. When I put this SELECT into mysql workbench it will select right values. I check column types and they are same type as variables in trigger.
With debug I discovered that there is problem with SELECTing values.
Thank you in advance.

Here is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER fin_den_zam_insert
AFTER INSERT
     ON table1 FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

DECLARE koef1 DECIMAL(6,3);
DECLARE koef2 DECIMAL(6,3);
DECLARE koef3 DECIMAL(6,3);
DECLARE sum DECIMAL(6,3);

SELECT DISTINCT
    koef_salary, koef_sunday, koef_holiday
INTO 
    koef1 , koef2, koef3 
FROM 
    employee E
WHERE 
    E.personal_number = NEW.personal_number_id;


SET sum := NEW.salary * (koef1 + koef2 + koef3);


INSERT INTO export_table
            (
                id_export,
                personal_number, 
                final_sum
                 ) 
VALUES 
            (
                NULL,
                NEW.personal_number_id, 
                sum
                ); 

END; 

//

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be careful with reserved words like sum, that can cause very much trouble.

most people write before every own variable _ like _sum, so that also a stranger can identify such variables.

That is as you can see not absolutely necessary, but helps also when you take a look in 5 years

> ```
> create table employee
> (personal_number int,koef_salary DECIMAL(6,3), koef_sunday DECIMAL(6,3), koef_holiday DECIMAL(6,3));
> ```

> ```
> create table export_table(
>                 id_export int auto_increment primary key,
>                 personal_number int, 
>                 final_sum DECIMAL(6,3)
>                  );
> ```

> ```
> CREATE table table1 
> (id_export int auto_increment primary key
> , personal_number_id int
> , salary DECIMAL(6,3));
> ```

> ```
> insert into employee values(1,1.1,1.3,1.4);
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER fin_den_zam_insert
> AFTER INSERT
>      ON table1 FOR EACH ROW
>
> BEGIN
>
> DECLARE koef1 DECIMAL(6,3);
> DECLARE koef2 DECIMAL(6,3);
> DECLARE koef3 DECIMAL(6,3);
> DECLARE final_sum DECIMAL(6,3);
>
> SELECT DISTINCT
>     koef_salary, koef_sunday, koef_holiday
> INTO 
>     koef1 , koef2, koef3 
> FROM 
>     employee E
> WHERE 
>     E.personal_number = NEW.personal_number_id;
>
>
> SET final_sum := NEW.salary * (koef1 + koef2 + koef3);
>
>
> INSERT INTO export_table
>             (
>                 id_export,
>                 personal_number, 
>                 final_sum
>                  ) 
> VALUES 
>             (
>                 NULL,
>                 NEW.personal_number_id, 
>                 final_sum
>                 ); 
>
> END
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (NULL,1,100)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM export_table
> ```
>
> ```
> id_export | personal_number | final_sum
> --------: | --------------: | --------:
>         1 |               1 |   380.000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb69e32a3dfb7db850a47a993183a068)*

Comment: Thank you for answer, but  I find out that error was caused by ommited E. in SELECT statement SELECT DISTINCT
    E.koef_salary, E.koef_sunday, E.koef_holiday
INTO 
    koef1 , koef2, koef3 
FROM 
    employee E
WHERE 
    E.personal_number = NEW.personal_number_id;  When I added it now work, but it is very strange why it works in db fiddle as you showed but it didn't work in MYSQL workbench.